# Show that $S_n/n$ is $C(0,1)$

Tags: probability

Given that $X_1,\ldots,X_2$ are independent and $C(0,1)$ (Cauchy distributed). We set $S_n = X_1+\cdots+X_n$.

We have to show that $\frac{1}{n}S_n\in C(0,1)$.

I do this by finding the charasteristic function of $X$ which is $\varphi_X(t)=e^{-\mid t \mid}$

Then, we know that $\varphi_{S_n}(t)=(\varphi_X(t))^n$ thus we have then: $\varphi_{S_n}(t)=e^{\mid t \mid n}$.

Now in this case, how is $\frac{1}{n}e^{\mid t \mid n}$ a charasteristic function of $C(0,1)$?

Comment: What is $C(0,1)$?

Comment: its cauchy distribution

Comment: Your last "$1/n$" is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are  almost there. You must only notice that, if $Z=aY$ then

$$\varphi_Z(t)=E(e^{itZ})=E(e^{itaY})=\varphi_Y(at)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\varphi_{S_n/n}(t) = \mathbb E\left( e^{t(S_n/n)} \right) = \mathbb E\left( e^{(t/n)S_n} \right) = \varphi_{S_n}\left( \frac{t}{n} \right) = \left(e^{-\left|t/n\right|}\right)^n = \cdots
$$

Answer (score 2):

You made a mistake when computing $\varphi_{S_n}(t)$. It shall be $e^{-|t|n}$. To handle factor $\frac1n$, just replace $t$ to $\frac tn$ and you will obtain
$$\varphi_{S_n/n}(t)=e^{-|\frac tn|n}=e^{-|t|}$$
Hence the Cauchy distribution $C(0,1)$.

Comment: thanks guys! always appreciate your help!